# Clipboard API - return value as html format

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the text from the clipboard in HTML format? the below code returns the text as plain text.

```
navigator.clipboard.readText()
.then(text => {
    console.log(text);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Something went wrong', err);
})
```

Comment: There is no such thing as _HTML format_. You either convert string with HTML to DOM or not. So no, you can't return it in any format. E.g. to use it as JSON: `JSON.parse(text)`

Comment: You can combine the data to a HTML object with jquery

Comment: Could you add the desired output to your post?

Comment: @Justinas - I'm not sure I follow your comment. The clipboard can indeed contain HTML, specifically (a clipboard item with `text/html` as its MIME type). For instance, when you copy text in a browser, it's typically copied both as plain text and as HTML so that you can paste the HTML into HTML-aware programs like word processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read any HTML in the clipboard, you can use the [`navigator.clipboard.read`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/read) method, find the [`ClipboardItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem) within the resulting array that offers HTML (if there is one), and then read that HTML from the item, like this:

```js
/**
 * Read any HTML from the clipboard.
 *
 * @returns A promise that will be fulfilled with the HTML or `undefined` if none
 *          is available, or that will be rejected if any error occurs reading
 *          the clipboard (such as permission from the user being denied).
 */
async function readClipboardHTML() {
    const items = await navigator.clipboard.read();
    const htmlItem = items.find(({types}) => types.includes("text/html"));
    if (htmlItem) {
        const htmlBlob = await htmlItem.getType("text/html");
        const html = await htmlBlob.text();
        return html;
    }
}
```

Note that you'll need to have permission from the user for your page to access the clipboard in this way. (Which is why I didn't do a Stack Snippet — they're sandboxed such that they don't allow the browser to ask the user for permission.)

Here's an example you can copy and paste to run on `localhost` to see it working (since it seems basically all of the online services sandbox things such that permission can't even be requested):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <title>Clipboard HTML Demonstration</title>
    <style>
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    .error {
        color: #d00;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>You can <strong>copy this paragraph</strong> to make sure you have HTML in your clipboard.</p>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Get Clipboard HTML">
<script type="module" src="./clipboard-example.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
/**
 * Read any HTML from the clipboard.
 *
 * @returns A promise that will be fulfilled with the HTML or `undefined` if none
 *          is available, or that will be rejected if any error occurs reading
 *          the clipboard (such as permission from the user being denied).
 */
async function readClipboardHTML() {
    const items = await navigator.clipboard.read();
    const htmlItem = items.find(({types}) => types.includes("text/html"));
    if (htmlItem) {
        const htmlBlob = await htmlItem.getType("text/html");
        const html = await htmlBlob.text();
        return html;
    }
}

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    result.classList.remove("error");
    result.textContent = "";
    readClipboardHTML()
    .then((html) => {
        if (typeof html === "undefined") {
            result.textContent = `No HTML available in the clipboard`;
        } else {
            result.textContent = `HTML: ${html}`;
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        result.classList.add("error");
        result.textContent = `Error: ${String(error)}`;
    });
});
```